# How to make a image clickable in Advanced PDF/HTLM Templates

Tags: html, templates, pdf, netsuite

I want to add an image and make that image clickable and redirect to a link.
So my customer can pay me online.

But when I add the image and add the link. The image is not clickable.
I try to use the code source, making it a button but didn't work.

Can you help me?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/johnpmachado/image/upload/v1648212677/Artboard_1_qem3rs.png" style="width: 230px; height: 28px;" /></a>
```

Thank you!

Comment: the code seems to be working fine! please upvote my answer ;)

Comment: It's not.. when I generate the PDF in Netsuite.
I can't click the image..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**HTML**

```html
<a href="example.com"><img src="example.png"></a>
```

Comment: When I use that code, I can't click the image...

Comment: can you edit your question and add your code?